# Bash run string formatted command in a for loop

Tags: string, bash, for-loop

I am trying to run multiple similar commands using a for loop and string formatting.

I am able to create and then print the strings of the commands I would like to run:

```
$foo=( "bar" "baz" )
$for ((j=0;j<2;++j)); do printf "touch %s_file.txt; " "${foo[j]}"; done
touch bar_file.txt; touch baz_file.txt;
```

But I want to enter these strings as a command. Based on other questions I was thinking that `eval` would do what I need:

```
$for ((j=0;j<2;++j)); do eval "touch %s_file.txt; " "${foo[j]}"; done
-bash: bar: command not found
-bash: baz: command not found
```

I was expecting(or hoping) the output would be equivalent to the output of:

```
$touch bar_file.txt; touch baz_file.txt;
```

The `touch` here is just an example. I'm more interested in how to format a string and then run it as a command. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you're iterating by index, rather than `for prefix in "${foo[@]}"; do`? Shouldn't be any need to have `j` at all.

Comment: BTW -- could you be a bit more clear on **why** you're trying to use string-formatting? It creates a bunch of security exposure you wouldn't have if you did things the best-practices approach.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am fairly unfamiliar with bash so I don't always know what the best practices are. In terms of looping through using a counter, in my actual use case I am looping through multiple arrays, and indexing into them with `j`. Really I am using string formatting because it is something I know how to do. It's good to know that is not the correct way to perform this operation, I will investigate alternatives. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Re: iterating over multiple arrays, if your shell is bash 4.3 or ksh93, you might look at using namevars for the purpose. That said, doing that effectively is largely a good case for its own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there's no need for using string formatting to generate code here, or in general -- [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) describes the use cases and better-practice alternatives. This could be as simple as the following:

```
for j in in "${foo[@]}"; do touch "${j}_file.txt"; done
```

---

Second, if you *must*, do it like so:

```
printf -v cmd 'touch %q_file.txt; ' "${foo[@]}"
eval "$cmd"
```

This will set `cmd='touch bar_file.txt; touch baz_file.txt '`, and then execute it.

Use of `%q` when content is to be later parsed by a shell (as with `eval`) ensures that your array elements are formatted in a way that will survive shell-parsing -- so if you had `foo=( "name with spaces" 'name with $(rm -rf $HOME) dangerous content' )`, you would be correctly touching `'name with spaces_file.txt'` and `'name with $(rm -rf $HOME) dangerous content_file.txt'`, not executing the dangerous content and touching multiple files based on the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to put the whole command in a string, why not make a function to do the thing you want like:

```
update_file() {
    touch "$1"
}

foo=( "bar" "baz" )
for ((j=0;j<2;++j)); do
    update_file "$(printf "%s_file.txt" "${foo[j]}")"
done
```

then you can make that function do arbitrarily complex things with the files

As a general rule, variables hold data, not code.  You can sometimes make it work putting code into data, but that way lies dragons.  See [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for some good reading on that

Comment: actually, wait, sorry, I missed that you were taking out the `eval`. I'm sorry; that comment wasn't applicable.

Comment: (rather, without the `eval`, it would be `"$(printf '%s_file.txt' "${foo[j]}" )"`, with the quotes around the expansion to prevent string-splitting and glob expansion, and `%s` to emit whitespace &c. literally).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I actually beat you to that one ;)

Comment: @EricRenouf thanks for suggestion and link, it is very useful.

Comment: ...though, `update_file "${foo[j]}_file.txt"` would presumably do the same thing. :)